# Simple ffmpeg cutting of videos and storing in specific location

Tags: video, ffmpeg

How to cut a small segment from a video in ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg.exe -i F:\\Ims\\144\\TestRun\\12907\\144151__cam144__10-10-2013 8.32.36 PM__10-10-2013 8.52.55 PM.avi -ss 00:00:01 -t 00:01:00 -vcodec -acodec -o F:\\IMS_Analysis\\cam144_0.avi
```

Gives an error that the option "-o" is not know. How do I ask ffmpeg create the output file called cam144_o.avi? what is the switch for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option needed for the output. In addition you included `-vcodec` and `-acodec` but you did not specify your desired codecs.

Try this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.avi -ss 00:00:01 -t 00:01:00 -codec copy -map 0 output.avi
```

This will [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) instead of re-encode so it will be fast and you will not loose any quality. I added `-map 0` to copy all streams from the input; otherwise the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) will only copy one stream per stream type. For example if `input.avi` contained two video streams then both will be copied instead of just one.